# Single sign-on using node JS HTML while already signed on on Sharepoint

Tags: node.js, html, sharepoint

My requirement is like - When User is already logged into Sharepoint then he does not need to enter his/her credentials on application.
Here i am using Node JS and HTML page to fetch Sharepoint information and rendering on page.
Every time Site/application is refreshed then it's asking for user credentials.
It should not ask while user is already signed-in to Sharepoint.

I have not tried anything as i have no idea and also i never worked on Sharepoint.

Note :- users are signing using AD account.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify:

- what sort of data it is (list/file/library/search/other?)
- *how* you're accessing data
- what version of SharePoint
- what the auth configuration is for SharePoint? (NTLM, Kerberos, ADFS etc)

As a node dev, you may want to look at proxying the data using sp-pnp-node or [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patrickrodgers/2016/10/17/using-pnp-js-core-and-node-sp-auth/). This could bypass the issue, but lack of pass-through or user-based auth could accidentally over-expose info. Depends on your use case.

Comment: I am fetching sharepoint list/view/library using node js in html file and rendering the xml pages based on library we arepassing through nodejs.
We are using sharepoint 2013 version and using ADFS configuration.
Can we find out which Users are logged-in to Sharepoint site?

Comment: Yuck! Why not at least use the SharePoint REST _api ? 
Anyway, take a look at that developer article, it should help.

You may also find this does what you want with less overhead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service